# React js componentDidUpdate not called when state changed

Tags: reactjs

**Hi I am a beginner in React and trying to build my first app**

login.js

```
import React from 'react'
import LoginForm from './loginForm'
import SignUpForm from './signUpForm'
import Home from './home'

class LoginPopUp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            signup: false,
            login: true,
            loginSuccess: false,
        }
        this.renderLogin = this.renderLogin.bind(this)
        this.renderSignUp = this.renderSignUp.bind(this)
        this.uponSuccessfulLogin = this.uponSuccessfulLogin.bind(this)
    }

    renderSignUp() {
        this.setState({signup: true, login: false})
    }

    renderLogin() {
        this.setState({signup: false, login: true})
    }

    uponSuccessfulLogin() {
        this.setState({loginSuccess: true})
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.signup) {
            return <SignUpForm renderLogin={this.renderLogin}/>
        } else if (this.state.login) {
            return <LoginForm renderSignUp={this.renderSignUp} uponSuccessfulLogin={this.uponSuccessfulLogin}/>
        } else if (this.state.loginSuccess) {
            return <Home/>
        }
    }
}

export default LoginPopUp;
```

loginForm.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { post } from 'axios';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state ={
        username: '',
        password: '',
        loginSuccess: '',
        submit: false,
      }
      this.onUsernameChange = this.onUsernameChange.bind(this)
      this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)
      this.onLoginSubmitButton = this.onLoginSubmitButton.bind(this)
      this.authenticate = this.authenticate.bind(this)
      this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)
    }

    onUsernameChange(e) {
        this.setState({username: e.target.value})
    }

    onPasswordChange(e) {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value})
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.loginSuccess) {
            if (this.state.loginSuccess === 200) {
                this.props.uponSuccessfulLogin()
            } else {
                alert("Authentication Failed! Provide valid credentials.")
            }
        }
    }

    authenticate() {
        const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/';
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', this.state.username);
        formData.append('password', this.state.password);
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }
        post(url, formData, config)
          .then(response => response.status)
          .then(status => this.setState({loginSuccess: status}))
    }

    onLoginSubmitButton() {
        this.authenticate()
    }

    handleButtonClick() {
        this.props.renderSignUp()
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.loginSuccess){
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <form className='LoginForm' onSubmit={this.onLoginSubmitButton}>
                        <label>
                            Username:
                            <input onChange={this.onUsernameChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label>
                            Password:
                            <input type='password' onChange={this.onPasswordChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <input type='submit' value='Submit'></input> 
                    </form>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                    <span>Not a member? </span>
                    <button id="clickHere" onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
                        Click here to SignUp
                    </button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

**When post (**.then(status => this.setState({loginSuccess: status}))** ) is successful I expect componentDidUpdate is called and `<Home/>` is rendered but here it doesn't render `<Home/>` instead I get same login page.  Please help me understand what did I do wrong.**

Comment: make sure you are not getting any error by chaining the `catch` block with the `then` block

Comment: Also make sure your `render` function returns something. It can be `null` but not `undefined` like now.

Comment: @MorKadosh even with rendering null I didn't get expected result.....

Comment: @Yousaf  I have put catch block and there were no errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because in `componentDidUpdate` you are calling `this.props.uponSuccessfulLogin()` where only `loginSuccess` is getting updated but `login` is still `true`. Hence even though you provided valid credentials even after getting `200` you are still seeing `Login` Page.

Make below changes to the parent component method `uponSuccessfulLogin`

```js
uponSuccessfulLogin() {
   this.setState(() => ({loginSuccess: true, signup: false, login: false}))
}
```

By doing so, since `signup` and `login` will be set to false and then `Home` component will be visible.

Also in your `loginForm.js` component, `return null` if you doesn't want to render anything.

```js
authenticate(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //..rest of the code
}

onLoginSubmitButton(e) {
   this.authenticate(e);
}

render() {
        if (!this.state.loginSuccess){
            //..rest of your code for displaying Login form
        } else return null;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but the problem here is this.props.uponSuccessfulLogin() is not called at all....I tried using visualcode debugger.....

Comment: Can you check the response of `post(url, formData, config)` in `authenticate` method once.

Comment: Object {data: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK", …}   this is response value.....

Comment: I tried console.log(response) but when checked the console for some reason  it just prints and then quickly disappears, like it is rendering login.js again...

Comment: By considering form submit default behaviour also into consideration as @Yousaf said, have updated my code. Please try this once.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call `Event.preventDefault()` function to prevent page from reloading when form is submitted

```
onLoginSubmitButton(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.authenticate();
}
```

[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) will disable the default behaviour of the browser when form is submitted.

Comment: this solution worked but still I have some other issues in other code...

Thanks Yousaf

Answer (score 0):

you need to set both `signup` and `login` to `false` in `uponSuccessfulLogin` in order for your code to reach last `else if` case

```
 uponSuccessfulLogin() {
        this.setState({loginSuccess: true, signup: false, login: false})
    }
```

Comment: Tried this solution but still I get same login page not the home page....I tried debugging in visualcode and it doesn't call uponSuccessfulLogin method  at all....

Answer (score 0):

try this in `loginForm` when updating login success :

```
this.setState(currentState=>({...currentState, loginSuccess:status))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

and check the status for `201 (created)` to complete the test example

you must have to prevent default events

```
  onLoginSubmitButton(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.authenticate();
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-leavitt-ctil9